# $.couch.session returns userctx with null name

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, couchdb, restful-authentication

I'm calling the following code:

```
$.couch.login($.extend({ name: "harry", password: "secrets"}, callback));
$.couch.session(callback);
```

where "harry" is just a dummy user I created using `$.couch.signup` and `callback` is a simple object specifying success/error/complete functions with bodies like these:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(data);
}
```

This code returns the following:

```
Success
Object {ok: true, name: "harry", roles: Array[0]}

Success
Object {ok: true, userCtx: Object, info: Object}
```

The first return is fine, but the second, the one from `session`, the `userCtx` object is basically empty, with a `null` name.

Also, when I try to login using my personal username and password (the ones I use as a Futon admin), this is returned:

```
Success
Object {ok: true, name: null, roles: Array[1]}
(0: "_admin")

Success
Object {ok: true, userCtx: Object, info: Object}
```

and fascinatingly, the first request knows seems to know I'm an admin, but doesn't get any other data, and the second request does the same thing as the previous example.

Any thoughts? Am I not using `$.couch.session` correctly? Is there something wrong with my couch instance?

FYI I am using version 1.4.0 and built from source.

Comment: I'm also finding that running `$.couch.db('_users').openDoc('org.couchdb.user:'+data.name, callback);` from a `success` method of `$.couch.login` call isn't finding a user record when it _should_ be, but it does properly from curl when an appropriate `username:password@` is added to `localhost`. I really think this `$.couch.session` is screwing me somehow.

Comment: Do I have to do something that manually passes the authentication cookie? It seems to me like that would be taken care of by the `$.couch` library.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out all I really needed was an [apache reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html). The couch instance didn't have access to the `AuthSession` cookie, since it was coming from port `5984`. Now things work great with the following added to my `apache2.conf` (may be `httpd.conf` for some)

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so

ProxyPass /_couch http://localhost:5984 nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /_couch http://localhost:5984
```

Comment: [nginx](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) works just as well by the way. Having everything on the same domain eliminated my many troubles as well.